# Cannot get 'bio', 'industry', 'professional headline' and 'number of connections' information from linkedIn

Tags: ios, linkedin-api, gigya

I am unable to get 'bio', 'bio', 'industry', 'professional headline' and 'number of connections' information from linkedIn with r_fullprofile permission. Though I am getting other information.

Is there anything they may have changed? I am using **Gigya** for it and Linkedin Extended Permission Info is set to **Enable retreiving full information** too.

Answer (score 1):

Recently few changes have been made to linked in developer program.Please refer below details.

API availability

After the grace period expires, several REST API endpoints will no longer be available for general use.  The following endpoints are the only ones that will remain available for use:

Profile API — /v1/people/~ 
Share API — /v1/people/~/shares 
Companies API — /v1/companies/{id}
If your application is currently using any other API services (e.g. Connections, Groups, People Search, Invitation, Job Search, etc.) you will have to apply to become a member of a relevant Partner Program that provides the necessary API access to continue to leverage any of the endpoints that are not listed above.

For more details check below link.

https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition

Comment: This answer is correct.  LinkedIn has changed what data is made available without applying to one of the developer partnership programs.  Although you have the permission set in Gigya, Gigya will only retrieve the relevant information if your LinkedIn Application has been approved to be a part of one of the relevant programs.